# Issue with deploying application using tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy an application using spring in tomcat7 running on ubuntu12.  When I drop the war file in the webapps directory, the directory is created for the application inside webapps - yet the application does not load up.  Latest issue is copied below.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting this will be appreciated.

Java versions are the same on the computers where the war file was generated vs the one where I am deploying the application.  I do not see a file permission issue - there is a logging.properties file in tomcat7.

```
Jan 31, 2014 10:43:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 31, 2014 10:43:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/test-webapp] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 31, 2014 10:43:05 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/test-webapp] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Update: 
I missed an error message.  I will update this ticket shortly.

Update:
I was missing a file in tomcat meant for the application deployment - pilot error.  Thanks to everyone for sharing their thoughts- much appreciated!

Comment: There must be more to the log than that. Please check.

Comment: Is the context file in place?

Comment: I missed an error message - will update shortly - thanks

Comment: sorry for wasting everyone's time - I missed an error message - I think its best that I close this ticket as opposed to updating it.  Thank you to everyone!

Comment: @alihaider Before you delete it, take note of Jorge's answer. There is a bug in MySQL driver when shutting down.

Comment: sure - will do if it helps others

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a known issue of MySQL over tomcat, have you tried yet any of the suggested solutions in

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69526

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68556

?

Comment: I missed an error message in the logs - investigating  - will update the post when possible -thanks

Comment: this was not causing the issue but is very useful info - thank you for sharing  - +1